# Convert .dat file to .jpg or .png

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I need to convert images under `.dat` format to `.jpg` or `.png` format. I searched around stackoverflow but can not find right answer. I tried following code:

```
   import numpy as np
   datfile = "car_image.dat"
   # Read file into Numpy array as uint8
   na = np.fromfile(datfile , dtype=np.uint8)
   print(na.shape)
```

The code above print `(65269,0)` but I do not know what to do next to convert it to `.png` or `.jpg` image. Could you please help me, thank you!

Comment: Specifically, what do you mean by a "dat" file? That's not a standard file type. I've seen many things with that file extension.

Comment: @Chris Thank for your attention. I am working on N-Cars dataset, when I unzip the dataset give me `.dat` files. The files represent for car images, I need convert them to png or jpg format for processing later.

Comment: What width/height image does it represent, because 65269 is prime?

Comment: @MarkSetchell It's what make me confuse, the dataset does not tell me width/height information. https://www.prophesee.ai/dataset-n-cars-download/. When I print shape of all numpy arrays read from the dat files, it prints completely odd numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misunderstood what you have downloaded.

These are not images, they are event-based data sets, which is why they ship `.dat` files and not images. This is written right below the download link you posted:

> Prophesee’s N-CARS dataset, a large real-world *event-based dataset* for car classification

And from [GEN-1, another dataset](https://www.prophesee.ai/2020/01/24/prophesee-gen1-automotive-detection-dataset/) released by Prophesee which seems to use the same encoding:

> Each dat file is a binary file in which events are encoded using 4 bytes (unsigned int32) for the timestamps and 4 bytes (unsigned int32) for the data, encoding is little-endian ordering.

They also provide [an ipynb tutorial](https://github.com/prophesee-ai/prophesee-automotive-dataset-toolbox/blob/master/tutorial.ipynb) explaining how to interact with them. Summarized:

```
import numpy as np
from src.io.psee_loader import PSEELoader

# open a file
video = PSEELoader("some_file_td.dat")
print(video)  # show some metadata
video.event_count()  # number of events in the file
video.total_time()  # duration of the file in mus

# let's read some Events , there are two ways by number of events or by time slices
events = video.load_n_events(10)  # this loads the 10 next events
events

# let's randomly drop some events
np.random.choice(events, len(events)//2)

# let's now try to read 10ms worth of events
events = video.load_delta_t(10000)
```

and so on...

Comment: "*The data is composed of 14 bits for the x position, 14 bits for the y position and 1 bit for the polarity (encoded as -1/1).*" https://www.prophesee.ai/2018/03/13/dataset-n-cars/ It appears to have some sort of pixel data.

Comment: Indeed, _it is_ "some sort of pixel data" but it is not directly convertible into images.

Comment: You could just put them into an image and get something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmWL0.png). But I doubt that's what OP expects.